# What are seasonal and perennial ponds?

Tags: geography

I stumbled upon these terms in a text related to [Pisciculture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_farming) (fish farming).
I've looked on Google and Google-books but I couldn't find any type of definition.

P.S. Please let me know if I posted it in the right community.

Comment: Do you mean natural ponds, or (since you reference Pisciculture) artifical ones?  For natural ponds, there are many hereabouts (Sierra Nevada) that are filled by rain & snow melt in the spring, but evaporate during the summer.  Searching for "vernal pool" or "vernal pond" might get you more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seasonal ponds are ponds that only exist for part of the year. Jamesqf covered it well in his comment. There is just a wide variety of terms explaining the same thing. The terms were originally used more for streams ([Perennial water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perennial_water)), but it has slid into broader usage.